# Swift various ways of creating empty array what are differences between them?

Tags: swift

I looked through docs some forums and found I can create an array in various ways. I am confused which one should we be using?

```
var testArray = [Int]()
testArray.append(1)

var anotherTestArray: [Int] = []
anotherTestArray.append(1)

var yetAnotherTestArray: Array<Int> = []
yetAnotherTestArray.append(1)

var yetYetYetAnotherTestArray = Array<Int>()
yetYetYetAnotherTestArray.append(1)
```

This is not empty array but It keeps it's type for each element to be strictly to an Int

```
var yetYetAnotherTestArray = [1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest way to create an array is `var testArray: [Int] = []`

In swift array objects must be the same type. If you want to store different objects of different types use `[AnyObject]`. However, you should always know what is coming out of it. Since the returning type value will be `AnyObject`, you have to cast down the value to the type you want.

I really don't recommend using `AnyObject` as the type of your arrays unless you really know what you are doing.

Here is an example anyway:

```
let a: [AnyObject] = [1, "a"]
let b = a[0] // An Int
let c = a[1] // A String
```

Comment: Hello, In Playground I am able to do this without AnyObject
```var testArray2 = ["int", 1]```

Comment: Also Can you please tell me difference between ```Array<Int>``` and ```[Int]```
Thank you

Comment: Swift infers the type when you don't specify it. In this case `var testArray2 = ["int", 1]` it will infer it is `AnyObject`. The type `Array<Int>` is equivalent to `[Int]`

Comment: @OscarVGG Actually, the type will be inferred as `[NSObject]`.

Comment: I prefer `var testArray = [Int]()` over `var testArray: [Int] = []` because it's shorter.